# Replace a string with an universal tag in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

How can i replace a string with universal tag in Drupal. So that wherever the tag is used in content the string is displayed

Answer (score 0):

May be the [scanner](https://www.drupal.org/project/scanner) module will help you for doing this.

If you are not searching for this, please give more details about your requirement.